# Passing UILabel to Facebook using ShareKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, sharekit

On a recommendation I've added ShareKit to my app, I'd like to send the contents of a UILabel to Facebook. After trying

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:labelText];
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

It crashes with -[UILabel length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8279600

I've tested it out using simple text to make sure I didn't mess any of the installation up and it worked flawlessly.

I'm starting to think it's my code as I'm still learning.

Any thoughts?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to send the text and not the UILabel
So change the following

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:labelText];
```

to

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:labelText.text];
```